# error not a package C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm

Tags: npm

I am new to node and npm and have been tryng to update npm from version 1.4.3 o the latest one. The procedure I am following to do this is

> navigate to C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs with cmd.exe and then run
> the installation without -g: npm install npm (from [npm github](https://github.com/npm/npm/wiki/Troubleshooting#upgrading-on-windows))

The problem is that when I run

> npm install npm

I get

> npm ERR! not a package C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm
>
> npm ERR! addLocal Could not install C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm
>
> npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.2.9200
>
> npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\Program
> Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" "npm"
>
> npm ERR! node v0.10.30
>
> npm ERR! npm  v2.2.0
>
> npm ERR! path
> C:\Users\ADMINI~1.PLA\AppData\Local\Temp\3\npm-9796-44646cae\unpack-c30e5ffdacdb\package.json
>
> npm ERR! code ENOENT
>
> npm ERR! errno 34
>
> npm ERR! enoent ENOENT, open
> 'C:\Users\ADMINI~1.PLA\AppData\Local\Temp\3\npm-9796-44646cae\unpack-c30e5ffdacdb\package.json'
>
> npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
>
> npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
>
> npm ERR! enoent
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:

But after this when I run

> npm --version

it shows me

> N:\Program Files\nodejs>npm -v
>
> 2.2.0

but from some other folder it still shows me

> N:\Program Files>npm -v
>
> 1.4.3

So, how can I fix this.

Answer (score 7):

I think the first error (`not a package`) is coming because `npm` is looking at the filesystem and sees the `npm` command before it looks at the `npm` registry.  You can work around that by running `npm install npm@latest`

It looks like a couple of things are wrong.  Here's what I would suggest:

1. Upgrade to the latest node (0.10.35) http://nodejs.org/download/
2. Follow the `npm` update instructions from here: https://github.com/npm/npm/wiki/Troubleshooting#upgrading-on-windows  (though it looks like you are already doing this).
3. Close and re-open your terminal (cmd.exe or bash) windows so that they definitely have the new PATH and the new `npm`.

If that doesn't work, please post your PATH environment variable - you can print this from cmd.exe by running `echo %PATH%` at the `>` prompt, or from a bash terminal by running `echo $PATH`.  There may be more than one installation of npm in your path, which would mess things up.

Comment: Great advice. Got to run it as admin, though.